# Is vim suitable for professional development inside a company?

Tags: vimrc, ide

How commonly is Vim used in professional software development today, inside a company? By Vim, I mean the actual Vim editor, not a Vim/vi plugin/setting or usage within Eclipse.

Has Vim hindered your daily programming work when you had to interact with other tools or frameworks?

Has Vim hindered your social interaction with other team members in some way?

How did your colleagues and bosses respond in general, that you wanted to use an editor which forces you to configure it, instead of an ready-to-use IDE?

(Sure, every IDE needs to be configured for the project. I just think Vim requires more configuration before being able to use it effectively. I assume this wouldn't create a good impression at work.)

Have you pair-programmed with non-Vim users?

I assume that people are already familiar with Vim and don't start configuring Vim at work.

Comment: I'm closing this question as 'primarily opinion based'. This *doesn't* mean this is a bad or invalid question as such, but rather that it doesn't fit this site's format very well. This is a good topic for a *debate site*, where people can respond to each other and discus various points, which is something you can't really do here because that's not what it was designed for...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm not sure what to do now. Two years after I asked this question, I found a suitable answer. To sum it up: Vim is suitable for professional development if certain tools are available for the usage within vim (a good debugger, autocompletion based on the source which is edited, jumping to a symbol's definition, tools for auto formatting the source based on some coding style definitions). That means, it depends on the language you're editing. C/C++ seems to be very suitable, but java is not, because no good debugger exists. So vim is suitable for developing C/C++ but not java.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker therefore i still think my question is valid, although it was poorly written. Therefore, i would like to reopen this question. :)

Comment: Well, that's a perfectly valid but opinionated statement @toogley, that quite a few would probably disagree with. The point of the Stack Exchange sites is to have specific, narrow, and objectively answerable questions, whereas this is an open-ended, broad, and opinionated question. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, this doesn't mean it's a "bad" question, it's just not the sort of question that this site was built to deal with.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker so do i understand you correctly: you think its opinionated, because some people don't need a debugger (like "gdb" for C programming) and are satisfied with "println(VariableName)" debugging? And therefore, those people think vim IS suitable for java development?

Comment: Yes, you've got it :-) It's also very broad, especially as stated now (I count at least five questions. A good question would be something like "How can I integrate a debugger in Vim?" or "How can I autoformat my code?", and so forth (many of these questions have *already* been asked – and usually answered – by the way).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This an odd question, and would be equally odd if asked of *any* editor IMHO.

No, vim (nor any other vi-variant) has ever hindered any of my work. I've only ever been hindered when *not* using it.

I'm not sure how vim would hinder my social interaction with other team members. It's not like vim gives you bad breath.

My colleagues and bosses couldn't care less what editor I use. About 70% of them use vim/vi too, a handful use emacs, most of the GUI developers use Eclipse, and one or two might use something else like jEdit or Notepad++. They don't care what brand of pen I take notes with either.

Also, I don't see how vim *forces* you to configure it. Out of the box, it works pretty much like any version of vi ever has. Yeah, you end up tweaking it to your liking over time, but probably less than any IDE.

I haven't done any official pair programming, although two of us sometimes do work together to solve a particularly thorny problem. But then again, I don't see that the choice of editor matters much (everyone here except perhaps some of the GUI developers at least know how to use vim/vi, even if it's not their editor of choice).